# Passing variable as lookup value for application.vlookup function returns #N/A

Tags: vba, vlookup

`Worksheets("outputraw").Cells(1,4)` contains a Date, lets say (09/09/2015)
`Worksheets("outputraw").Range("a:b")` looks as follows:

```
Col A       Col B
09/09/2015  2592.795
10/09/2015  2588.904
11/09/2015  2571.05
14/09/2015  2598.988
15/09/2015  2605.902
16/09/2015  2613.178
```

Code:

```
sub VlookupProblem()

dim Var as Date
Var = Worksheets("outputraw").Cells(1,4).Value 'meaning 09/09/2015
Worksheets("outputraw").Cells(1, 5) = Application.VLookup(Var, Worksheets("outputraw").Range("a:b"), 2, True) ' this returns #N/A or error 1004 if i debug with WorksheetFunction

Worksheets("outputraw").Cells(1, 6) = Application.VLookup(Worksheets("outputraw").Cells(1, 4), Worksheets("outputraw").Range("a:b"), 2, True) ' this returns the value i need, meaning 2592.795

end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the date.  A date is a formatted number and at times it is hard to get the exact date when passing through variables.

I like to compare the `.value2` to each other instead.

```
Sub VlookupProblem()

Dim Var

Var = Worksheets("outputraw").Cells(1, 4).Value2 'meaning 09/09/2015
msgbox var
Worksheets("outputraw").Cells(1, 5) = Application.VLookup(Var, Worksheets("outputraw").Range("a:b").Value2, 2, True)
msgbox Worksheets("outputraw").Range("A5").Value2
Worksheets("outputraw").Cells(1, 6) = Application.VLookup(Worksheets("outputraw").Cells(1, 4), Worksheets("outputraw").Range("a:b"), 2, True)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Scott. I tried using .value, .value2, .text, .formula. None seem to work.

Comment: @Sasha did you use value2 in both places, when assigning the variable, Var and in the vlookup formula `Worksheets("outputraw").Range("a:b").Value2`?. if so then put two msgbox in.  I edited my code.  use it and let me know what is being returned.